# Modification to the CMakeLists txt file in order to build a project with many source files

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I was wondering how to build a project which contains 3.cpp files and 2.h headers. First, I create a package called test. Then I defined a 3.cpp files: main , ROSMath and Math.cpp. But when I try to build with catkin, I got this error  :

1/CMakeLits:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(test)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependency has been pulled in
##     but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
add_message_files(
   FILES
   
 )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
add_service_files(
   FILES
   TwoInts.srv
 )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )

################################################
## Declare ROS dynamic reconfigure parameters ##
################################################

## To declare and build dynamic reconfigure parameters within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for "dynamic_reconfigure"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "dynamic_reconfigure" to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * uncomment the "generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options" section below
##     and list every .cfg file to be processed

## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
# generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
#   cfg/DynReconf1.cfg
#   cfg/DynReconf2.cfg
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if your package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES test
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a C++ library
# add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/test.cpp
# )

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Declare a C++ executable
## With catkin_make all packages are built within a single CMake context
## The recommended prefix ensures that target names across packages don't collide
# add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/test_node.cpp)

## Rename C++ executable without prefix
## The above recommended prefix causes long target names, the following renames the
## target back to the shorter version for ease of user use
## e.g. "rosrun someones_pkg node" instead of "rosrun someones_pkg someones_pkg_node"
# set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_node PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME node PREFIX "")

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
# target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
# )

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
# install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_test.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)


add_executable(main src/main.cpp src/ROSMath.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(main test_gencpp)
```

2/Math.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_MATH_H
#define TEST_MATH_H



class Math
{

public:


static int add (int a , int b ) ;
    
};

#endif
```

3/ROSMath.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_ROSMATH_H
#define TEST_ROSMATH_H
#include "test/Math.h"

class ROSMath 
{

private: 
Math theMath;

public:
 
  ROSMath(Math* aMath);

  bool ROSadd(test::TwoInts::Request &req,
           test::TwoInts::Response &res);
};

#endif
```

4/Math.cpp:

```
#include "test/Math.h"


    
int add(int a, int b)
{

return a+b;

}

5/ROSMath.cpp:
#include "test/Math.h"
#include "test/ROSMath.h"
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "test/TwoInts.h"


ROSMath::ROSMath(Math* aMath) {
theMath = aMath;

}

bool ROSMath:: ROSadd(test::TwoInts::Request &req,
                  test::TwoInts::Response &res);
{

res.sum = theMath->add( req.a , req.b);
ROS_INFO("request: x=%ld, y=%ld", (long int)req.a, (long int)req.b);
ROS_INFO("  sending back response: [%ld]", (long int)res.sum);
return true;

}

6/main.cpp:

#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "test/TwoInts.h"
#include "test/ROSMath.h"
#include "test/Math.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "add_two_ints_test_server");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

// %Tag(SERVICE_SERVER)%

  Math op; 
  ROSMath ROSop(&op);
  ros::ServiceServer ss = n.advertiseService("add_two_ints_test", &ROSMath::ROSadd, &ROSop);
// %EndTag(SERVICE_SERVER)%

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

error:

```
CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o : Dans la fonction « main » :
main.cpp:(.text+0x107) : référence indéfinie vers « ROSMath::ROSMath(Math*) »
main.cpp:(.text+0x10d) : référence indéfinie vers « ROSMath::ROSadd(test::TwoIntsRequest_<std::allocator<void> >&, test::TwoIntsResponse_<std::allocator<void> >&) »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
test/CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:113 : la recette pour la cible « /home/hamza/catkin_ws/devel/lib/test/main » a échouée
make[2]: *** [/home/hamza/catkin_ws/devel/lib/test/main] Erreur 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7184 : la recette pour la cible « test/CMakeFiles/main.dir/all » a échouée
make[1]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Erreur 2
Makefile:138 : la recette pour la cible « all » a échouée
make: *** [all] Erreur 2
```

I think that is related to my CmakeLists.txt. Which modification shall I do to build my project successfully.

Thank You very much for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278375/modification-to-the-cmakelists-txt-file-in-order-to-build-a-project-with-many-source-files/) by [Hamza](https://answers.ros.org/users/33055/hamza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-12-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2017-12-29**:
Can you post the CMakeLists.txt file you're using along with the 5 source files you've mentioned. It looks like there are some errors in your code as well `main.cpp:(.text+0x107) : référence indéfinie vers « ROSMath::ROSMath(Math*)` looks like you're missing some #include 's

**Comment by [Hamza](https://answers.ros.org/users/33055/hamza/) on 2017-12-30**:
Hi Peter, thank you for your response, I edited my question in order to add the Cmakelist.txt file and the source files. I modified the add_excutables in the Cmakelist.txt as indicated by nrparikh and I got errors

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-30**:
@Hamza: could you please take care to format things properly next time when copying code/build scripts/console output? Just select and use `ctrl+k` or press the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it).

Also: please don't include the boilerplate comments in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you haven't linked your *.cpp files in the CMakeLists, you will face this error. As far as I understand, you are including ROSMath.cpp and Math.cpp in your main file and you will only have one executable. You should follow [ROS C++ tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.CA-56e552a9f29027036adb74aeea6375a15de4f70e_20). The modification here will be instead of adding just one file to your node, you will need to have more than one files linked to the same node. For e.g.

```
add_executable(foo src/foo.cpp src/bar.cpp src/foo2.cpp)
```

---

Originally posted by [nrparikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32891/nrparikh/) with karma: 16 on 2017-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamza](https://answers.ros.org/users/33055/hamza/) on 2017-12-30**:
Thank you for your response , I test what you suggested and I got errors :

In file included from /home/hamza/catkin_ws/src/test/src/ROSMath.cpp:2:0:
/home/hamza/catkin_ws/devel/include/test/ROSMath.h:14:15: error: ‘test’ has not been declared
bool ROSadd(test::TwoInts::Request & req,
/home/hamza

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-03**:
Hi it looks like a code error somewhere. Can you post the source of ROSMath.cpp and ROSMath.h and we'll be able to help you get this fixed.

**Comment by [Hamza](https://answers.ros.org/users/33055/hamza/) on 2018-01-08**:
Thank you very much for your reply, I already manage to fix all errors.